# ArgumentNullException when uploading photo to wall

Tags: c#, facebook-c#-sdk

When uploading a photo to a user's wall I get an ArgumentNullException, parameter "stream"

```
var fb = new FacebookClient();

fb.PostCompleted += (o, e) =>
{
    ...
};

dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
parameters.access_token = accessToken;
parameters.message = "test efesur";
var mediaObject = new FacebookMediaObject
      {
          ContentType = "image/png", 
          FileName = "mifoto.png"
      };
mediaObject.SetValue(photo);
parameters.source = mediaObject;

fb.PostAsync("me/photos", parameters);
```

A I missing something ?

Comment: Where does the exception occur?  What is the stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

According to [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9392016/facebook-c-sharp-sdk-throws-argumentnullexception) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7654379/application-generated-apprequests-failing-in-silverlight) you get that error when the API is unable to process your request for various reasons.